# Editing a comma-separated list of path,size pairs

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have lines of the form

```
parts=/a,1mb,/b/c,2gb,/zee/last,-1 #general form on next line
parts=path1,size1,...,lastPath,-1
```

I want to replace all `path1,size1` **except** `lastplace,-1` with `newPath,newSize` so that it looks like

```
parts=newPathX,newSizeX,lastPath,-1
```

I figured how to do it using *at least one instance* of ',' char as follows

```
sed 's|^parts=.*,\(.*,-1\)$|parts=newPathX,newSizeX,\1|gi'
```

but this breaks if the list only has the last path and size. For example, I want

```
parts=lastPath,-1
```

to be transformed to

```
parts=newPathX,newSize,lastPath,-1
```

So I tried to fix this with a conditional in bash:

```
egrep -i '^parts=.*,.*,-1$' $file
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
    sed 's|^parts=.*,\(.*,-1\)$|parts='$new',\1|gi' $inp
else
    sed -i -e 's|^parts=|parts='$new',_gi' $file
fi
```

I would like to know a pure sed solution as I can quickly understand it, but awk will do too.

Comment: I attempted to fix the format, but quickly gave up :(. @Some n00b - please format your code so we dont have to hire codebreakers.

Comment: puthere_new=/a,1kb,/b,2mb,/c,-1 will be change to what when newplace is /dd, and size is /2gb?

Comment: should I paste my bash quick as answer ? though I still want a combined 'regex magic' to solve this one ??

Comment: puthere_new=/dd,2gb,/c,-1 @Gadolin

Comment: You might be able to make this work using `sed`, but anchored regexes and the `g` modifier aren't going to do it. You'd have to do some looping and splitting with some swaps between pattern space and hold space. Your title, question and data are all such a mess I'm not going to attempt it. It would be pretty hairy anyway.

Comment: @Dennis : sorry, 1st timer here.. getting used to stack overflow.. so no clue how people go about Qs and providing Data

Answer (score 1):

Try using awk:

```
$ var='puthere=$place1,$size1,$place2,$size2,(..and so on..),$lastplace,-1'
$ echo "$var" | awk -F"[=,]" -vnp="$newplace" -vns="$newsize" '/puthere/{print "puthere="np,ns,$(NF-1),$NF}' OFS=","
puthere=test1,size1,$lastplace,-1
```

Comment: thank you very much for the nice 'awk' script, guess i'll have to start digging awk now :) But will it be too much to ask for single line sed magic ?
Thanks again !

Comment: I ask because the pattern comes as a line in a text file, can someone tell me how to convert above into something that will take $1=filename as argument and do the rest ?

Comment: there are times when things can be done simpler by not using sed.

Comment: hmm, I think I better customize your awk solution to my bash script, looks quite elegant :) 
I give up on sed :( !

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/^parts=.*,.*,-1$/ s|=.*,\([^,]*,-1\)$|=newPathX,newSizeX,\1|gi'
```

Sometimes, its also very simple in sed ;-). Just add a filter before to avoid your exception case